# Stored procedure enumeration not yielding any results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in my project, but the enumeration is not yielding any results.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Info about my project:

```
.NET Framework 4.5
<package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)
```

Manually using stored procedure works and returns the correct data:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetFeatures]
        @XMLDoc = N'<ArrayOfInt><int>280</int><int>286</int><int>279</int><int>292</int><int>277</int></ArrayOfInt>',
        @ReleaseId = 340

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Here's where I execute the stored procedure in my code:

```
public ObjectResult<GetFeatures_Result> GetFeatures(List<int> featureIds, int releaseId, int? timeboxId, int? teamId)
{
    string xmlFeatureIds = null;   

    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<int>)); 
    var ms = new MemoryStream(); 
    xs.Serialize(ms, featureIds.ToList()); 

    //xmlFeatureIds = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    xmlFeatureIds = "<ArrayOfInt><int>280</int><int>286</int><int>279</int><int>292</int><int>277</int></ArrayOfInt>";
    //releaseId = 340;
    var release = _rmContext.Releases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == releaseId);//works, Releases is just a table
    var obj = _rmContext.GetFeatures(xmlFeatureIds, releaseId, null, null); //enumeration didn't yield any results
    var obj2 = _rmContext.GetFeatures(xmlFeatureIds, releaseId, null, null).ToList(); //length of this is zero.

    return obj;
}
```

Model browser and visual studio setup:
[image]

EDIT:

From the SQL profiler:

```
declare @p1 xml
set @p1=convert(xml,N'<ArrayOfInt><int>280</int><int>286</int><int>279</int><int>292</int><int>277</int></ArrayOfInt>')
exec [dbo].[GetFeatures] @XMLDoc=@p1,@ReleaseId=340,@TimeBoxId=NULL,@TeamId=NULL
```

Comment: All of the info that you have provided is dancing around the problem. Use Sql Server Management Studio's Profiler to intercept the SQL that is being sent by EF to SQL Server and post it.

Comment: I've never used it before, but will try it out now and get back to you if needed asap. Thanks

Comment: How many results are returned when you execute the SP directly against the database; outside of your C# application?

Comment: The query you run in Management Studio is not the same if `@TimeBoxId` and/or `@TeamId` have default values. What does the stored procedure header look like?

Comment: That was it, @MartinSmith! In the SP it was listed as TimeBoxId int = 0, TeamId int = 0. Passing 0's instead of nulls in the c# portion gave me the correct results. Reply with an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query sent from your application passes an explicit value of `NULL` for the parameters `@TimeBoxId` and `@TeamId`.

The one you are testing in SSMS omits these parameters entirely.

If the parameters have defaults these are only applied when the parameters are omitted or the `DEFAULT` keyword is specified.

This explains the difference in behaviour.

I'm not sure if there is any way to get the EF generated query to do that but you can either alter the application to pass the desired default values of `0` instead of `NULL` or alter the stored procedure so the first step is.

```
SET @TimeBoxId = ISNULL(@TimeBoxId,0)
SET @TeamId = ISNULL(@TeamId,0)
```